# Error Ambiguous reference to member 'indices' in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, foreach, swiftui

I am trying to iterate over all the dates I have received from my API and convert them into a usable format for my app. I am running into an error with this code

```
 ForEach(dateList.indices, id: \.self) { date in
    self.que = "";
    for letter in dateList[date] {
       if letter == "T" {
          dateList[date] = self.que
          return
       }
       else if letter == "-" {
          self.que = self.que + "/"
       }
       else {
         self.que = self.que + letter;
      }
   }
}
```

I am trying to have this iterate over each string I have in the dateList array and convert it into a format that is usable in my app. This format is going from 2020-02-28T03:32:44Z to 2020/02/28. I am getting the error  "Ambiguous reference to member 'indices'" and I'm not sure what this means.

Comment: You should be using [DateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter) to retrieve dates from strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

struct `ForEach` is only using for showing views:

```swift
/// A structure that computes views on demand from an underlying collection of
/// of identified data.
@available(iOS 13.0, OSX 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
public struct ForEach<Data, ID, Content> where Data : RandomAccessCollection, ID : Hashable { ... }
```

for example you can use it to show rows of some `List`

```swift
List {
    ForEach(dateList.indices, id: \.self) { dateIndex in Text("\(self.dateList[dateIndex])") }
}
```

it's not about computing some variable like `que`, you should extract this computing into some function and call it from `onAppear` for example. Here is a little example of `ForEach` and `forEach` difference:

```swift
struct SomeLoopData: View {

    @State var dates = ["2020/02/28", "2020/02/29"]
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(dates.indices) { index in Text("\(self.dates[index])") }
                .onAppear {
                    self.compute()
            }
        }

    }

    func compute() {

        dates.indices.forEach { index in
            print(dates[index])
        }

    }
}
```